# CSS Image Sprites - Changing Display Setting Image Not Showing

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change images using CSS Sprites, now, the problem is that display: none; to display: block; is working from jQuery, but the image is not showing (I'm checking the HTML via FireBug and its changing but the image is not showing at all)

```
$('#logobrandingactive').css({'display': 'block'});
$('#logobranding').css({'display': 'none'});
$('#logobrandingactive').css('opacity','1');

#logobranding {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
    background-image: url("../images/servicesbranding.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
    top:175px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -81px;
    width: 162px;
    height: 162px;
}
#logobrandingactive {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
    background-image: url("../images/moservicesbranding.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 16;
    top:175px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -81px;
    width: 162px;
    height: 162px;
}
```

Comment: you could try the `visible` attribute with `hidden` and `visible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
.loader {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
  background:url(../path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; 
  display:none;
}
```

Hide and visible with JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".loader").show()// For visible; for hide use .hide()

 $(".loader").css({'background-image':'url(../path/to/image.jpg)'}); //Changing background image.

});
```